# How do I handle this situation: 'n/a' shows up as 'nan' in pandas dataframe, but cannot string-match it and replace

Tags: python, pandas, replace, nan, missing-data

I have a CSV file where a few lines are `n/a`. When I load it as a pandas dataframe, it shows as `nan`.

This causes problems when I use functions like `split`, `lower`, etc on those few lines.

```
data_df['column'][104]
>>> nan

data_df['column'][104].split()
>>> 
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-6efe06f0a4ec> in <module>()
----> 1 data_df['column'][104].split()

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

data_df['column'][104].lower()
>>>
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-c80cc9ae0712> in <module>()
----> 1 data_df['column'][104].lower()

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

When I try to replace the `nan`s with blanks (which does not cause these errors), with the `fillna` method, it does not do anything:

```
data_df.fillna('')

data_df['column'][104]
>>> nan
```

So I tried replacing it as a string:

```
for i in range(len(data_df)):
    if data_df['column'][i]=='nan':
        data_df['column'][i]=''

data_df['column'][104]
>>> nan

for i in range(len(data_df)):
    if data_df['column'][i]=='n/a':
        data_df['column'][i]=''

data_df['column'][104]
>>> nan
```

The following does not print anything:

```
for i in range(len(data_df)):
    if (data_df['column'][i]=='nan' or data_df['column'][i]=='n/a'):
        print(data_df['column'][i])
```

Why am I not able to catch and replace the `nan`s or `n/a`s? And how do I fix it?

Comment: You can try `df = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv' ,na_filter=False)` but that will not detect any missing value markers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can fix it at the beginning

```
df=pd.read_csv('Yourfile.csv',na_values=['n/a']).fillna('')
```

Comment: Interesting. It works. But why was I not able to catch the `n/a`s?

Comment: @Kristada673 you can catch it , just need assign it back , df=df.fillna('')

Answer (score 2):

`data_df.fillna('')` creates a copy of your dataframe. If you want to change the original dataframe, call `data_df.fillna('', inplace=True)`.